# Inserting data from an html page to php form as in auto-filling the value

Tags: php, html, forms, autofill

So here is the problem I have a page with 8 of these html boxes.
My company wants the #stk ###### to auto fill the form field "stock" when "make an offer" is selected.
I did get it to work but the code is very Jerry rigged the code is below the image. I'm just looking for a simpler and none Jerry rigged way to do this.

---

```
`<p>3.  <label for="stockNum">* Stock Item Number</label><br>
    <input name="stockNum" type="text" value="<?php
$stock1 =$_POST['stockNum1'];
$stock2 = $_POST['stockNum2'];
print "$stock1";
print "$stock2";
?>
">
`
```

Comment: It's a tad difficult to match the code you have with the description you've given.  is the "stock" field the "stockNum" field?  Is "make an offer" and button?  a Link?

Should these values populate after the browser refreshes or goes to a page, or asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a public web site you've got a bunch of problems with that approach, you would want to first filter the `$_POST['stockNum1']` variables so nobody tries something shady by inserting `javascript:` or something else naughty in to your site.

About your specific problem, auto-filling in forms is generally done with Javascript hardcoded or a Javascript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) which would allow you to just fill in the forms without having to post the data first.